# Error while freeing memory allocated for sorted subarray in merge sort

Tags: c, algorithm, free, mergesort

I have below merge_Sort() function which implements merge sort.

It does sort correctly (when I comment out the free() calls), but issue is there when I try to free the memory occupied by sorted sub-array.

```
/* merge_Sort() to merge array by didive and conquer*/
/* calls merge_v_1() to merge two sorted subarrays*/
/* merge_v_1() takes two sorted subarrays and copies them to new sorted array, and returns the pointer to this new sorted array*/
int *merge_Sort(int *array, int a, int b)
{
    if (a==b)
    return array;
   else
    {
         int middle = ((a+b)/2);
         int *left_Sub_Array, *right_Sub_Array;
         int *left_Sub_Array_1, *right_Sub_Array_1;

          left_Sub_Array = merge_Sort(array, a, middle);
          right_Sub_Array = merge_Sort((array + (middle - a + 1) ), middle + 1 ,b);

           left_Sub_Array_1 = left_Sub_Array;
           right_Sub_Array_1 = right_Sub_Array;

            int *newArray = malloc((b - a + 1) * (sizeof(int)));
            if (newArray == NULL)
             {
                  exit (1);
              }
             merge_v_1(left_Sub_Array_1, (middle - a + 1), right_Sub_Array_1, (b - middle), newArray);
         // PROBLEM IS HERE IN BELOW TWO FREE()
         free(left_Sub_Array);
         free(right_Sub_Array);
         return (newArray);
     }
}
```

Initially, I thought this was because, function merge_v_1() is changing the pointers `left_Sub_Array` and `right_Sub_Array`. So I thought of copying values of  `left_Sub_Array` and `right_Sub_Array` to `left_Sub_Array_1` and `right_Sub_Array_1`, and pass those those to merge_v_1(), so that values of `left_Sub_Array` and `right_Sub_Array` would not be changed. However, stil, I get issues while freeing the memory.

Below is a sample output.

```
user $ ./a.out
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002272014 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
user $
```

It looks like I am trying to free a memory which i am not supposed to, but I am not able to figure it out the root cause. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not create a new (separate) array of the same size as the array to be sorted, and use that as scratch space? It saves constant calls the malloc/free, saves time copying back and forth, and it's easier to understand and program.

Answer (score 2):

You have 1 malloc and 2 free's.  That is always a problem.  From wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

> The improper use of dynamic memory allocation can frequently be a source of bugs. These can include security bugs or program crashes,
>   most often due to segmentation faults.
>
> Most common errors are as follows:
>
> Not checking for allocation failures. Memory allocation is not
>   guaranteed to succeed, and may instead return a null pointer. If
>   there's no check for successful allocation implemented, this usually
>   leads to a crash of the program, due to the resulting segmentation
>   fault on the null pointer dereference. Memory leaks. Failure to
>   deallocate memory using free leads to buildup of non-reusable memory,
>   which is no longer used by the program. This wastes memory resources
>   and can lead to allocation failures when these resources are
>   exhausted. Logical errors. All allocations must follow the same
>   pattern: allocation using malloc, usage to store data, deallocation
>   using free. Failures to adhere to this pattern, such as memory usage
>   after a call to free (dangling pointer) or before a call to malloc
>   (wild pointer), calling free twice ("double free"), etc., usually
>   causes a segmentation fault and results in a crash of the program.
>   These errors can be transient and hard to debug – for example, freed
>   memory is usually not immediately reclaimed by the OS, and thus
>   dangling pointers may persist for a while and appear to work.

I would examine your logic around newArray and get rid of the second free.

Comment: One malloc() is to allocate memory and to return the pointer to `newArray`. This value of `newArray` is RETURNED to a `left_Sub_Array` or a `right_Sub_Array`. So when i am doing free (left_Sub_Array) or `free(right_Sub_Array)`i am trying to free the  memory pointed by `newArray` of the merge function which has already executed and RETURNED. Each time I am trying to allocate memory for new sorted array (so using ONE malloc), then merging the two already sorted array to this alocated memory. Then I am trying to `free` the old sorted subarrays. So 'two' frees. So this not the problem..

Comment: @sps Pretty sure it is.  You don't show merge_v_1, but that's where you should have your alloc, copy your elements into the new array, and return the pointer.  Then you can free your original array.  I wish you the best of luck!!  But as James T Smith said, a much better way is not use dynamic memory at all.

Comment: Yea, in the end I changed my algorithm and now I can free memory without issues. I am still using dynamic memory but its causing no problems here. But I am still not sure why the code in OP was having issues. Thanks for interest and advise anycase !!

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation is tricky, and not great to intermix with performance critical code(like sorting). Here's an example of an unsorted array with a corresponding auxiliary array for temporary storage. The advantage is 2 mallocs, followed by 2 frees. The disadvantage is 2x memory usage.

```
// Code from Algorithms 4th edition - Robert Sedgewick, et al.
int main(void)
{
 int somearray[10];
 // fill with data
 int tmp_space[10];

 sort(somearray, tmp_space, 0, 9);
}


void merge(int *a, int *aux, int lo, int mid, int hi)
{
 int i = lo, j = mid+1, k;
 memcpy(&aux[lo], &a[lo], sizeof *a *((hi - lo) +1));

 // copied memory to auxiliary space. Now add back to real
 // space in proper order.
 for (k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
  if (i > mid)
   a[k] = aux[j++];
  else if (j > hi)
   a[k] = aux[i++];
  else if (aux[j] < aux[i])
   a[k] = aux[j++];
  else
   a[k] = aux[i++];
 }
}

void sort(int *a, int *aux, int lo, int hi)
{
 if (hi <= lo) return;
 int mid = lo + ((hi - low)/2);

 // recursively break in half, and from the bottom up merge two halves.
 sort(a, aux, lo, mid);
 sort(a, aux, mid+1, hi);
 merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
}
```